# php mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

i have this piece of code that allow user to edit their profile from the form using php and mysql when i echo the submitted or changed value it display the right and the edit value but nothing change in the database  can anyone help me to solve this problem

this is the part that i am updating the query

if you need  any addition files let me know and thank you

## search.php

```
//submit whatthe user types into the database

     $fname = $_POST['fname'];
     $lname = $_POST['lname'];
     $country = $_POST['country'];
     $spec = $_POST['specialization'];

    ///errroor in updating the dataabse 


     $edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', address= '$country', specialization_name= '$spec' WHERE user_name = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: where is `$username` coming from?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

`$username` is not defined. As result the query is executed for no database row.

Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of [sql injectionable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) `mysql_query()`.

Comment: ahhhh the $username come from the session that i cried out  to each protected page

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the userName variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
$edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET first_name= '".$fname."', last_name= '".$lname."', address= '".$country."', specialization_name= '".$spec."' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());

//Make sure that your $username hold some valid value.
```

Comment: The string syntax isn't the issue.  If the OP's query didn't work, yours won't either.

Answer (score 0):

`$username` is required and your query is `vulnerable by sql injection`. so use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$spec = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specialization']);

$edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', address= '$country', specialization_name= '$spec' WHERE user_name = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```